# Create new version of app while previous version is Approved and Developer removed from sale

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Version 1.0 of our app is approved (developer removed from sale) and we are working on an update 1.1 to fix some small issues. **Is it possible to add a new version 1.1 of the app on Itunes Connect without compromising the current approved version?** Since the new version may not be approved in time for the release, we will release version 1.0.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

> You will only be able to add a new version for a new platform or a
>   platform that has a Ready for Sale or Developer Removed from Sale
>   version. If a platform version has not completed the app review
>   process—it has a status such as Prepare For Submission or Waiting For
>   Review—you can replace the build in the existing version instead of
>   adding a new version. See Removing a Build from Review.

Comment: your current version 1.0 right now available on iTunes store?

Comment: @RenishDadhaniya Version 1.0 is approved but not released (Developer Removed from Sale)

Comment: Ok, As per my knowledge you can do following way.Other solution may be possible. For Ex, Your current version 1.0(Build Number) is approved but removed from some reasons. Now, you need to keep version number same but you need to increased Build number. For Ex - 1.0(13) approved but removed due to some reason. Now, you will be able to upload 1.0(14) on app store.

Comment: @RenishDadhaniya It is not important to us to update 1.0. I just want to be sure that 1.0 can be released even if 1.1 is not approved in time.

Comment: Ok, I think you need to first of release 1.0 on apple store. Right now, you can upload 1.1 version on TestFlight and sent for a review. If apple approve this version 1.1 on testFlight then it will be 90% approved on production version.

Comment: Right now you will need to release 1.0 on apple store otherwise it is not possible because your app will start with 1.1 version. what about 1.0 version on apple store? because user not able to find 1.0.

Comment: @RenishDadhaniya Are you guessing or do you have facts? Version 1.0 is already approved but removed from sale temporarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112038/discussion-between-renish-dadhaniya-and-mattias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not upload a binary with same version number on iTunes after approving that version with successful review. You have to upload a new binary with an upgraded version number if you want to have updated build on the store.

To sell an app you previously removed from sale, you must put it back on sale in the territories you want it to be sold in.

Note:  If you remove a version from sale and then add a new version, the new version will remain Removed from Sale as well, even after it is approved by App Review. To release the new version, you need to clear the app for sale again.

Comment: The app is Developer Removed From Sale because it will not be released yet. We are working on a new version (1.1) = new binary. I just want to make sure that uploading this version doesn't affect the current version (1.0)

Comment: What do you want to do?  Release version 1.1 or 1.0?

Comment: If it will have a different version then definitely it will not affect the older one.

Comment: @WilliamGP 1.1 if it gets approved in time, otherwise 1.0

Comment: @SHIV So we can create the new version and put 1.0 back on sale as well? It sounds logical, but we don't want to take any risks this close to the deadline.

Comment: @Mattias "Approved" by Apple?

Comment: @Mattias I think I understand your problem now. You should probably just release version 1.0 and then submit version 1.1 for approval.  You can't submit version 1.1 to Apple for review while 1.0 is just sitting there waiting for developer release - you either have to release version 1.0 or delete it.